# How to copy, concatenate and minify multiple js and scss files to one using Gulp on Windows?

Tags: compilation, concatenation, gulp, bundling-and-minification, project-organization

I'am a new adept of Gulp. Dear gurus, please help me to organize my project on windows.
The structure of this project is:

```
root
 | bower_components
 | | bootstrap-sass
 | | | assets
 | | | | javascript
 | | | | | bootstrap.min.js (second input javascript)
 | | jquery
 | | | dist
 | | | | jquery.min.js (first input javascript)
 | template
 | | css (output folder for stylesheets)
 | | js (output folder for javascripts)
 | | scss (input folder for scss)
 | | | variables.scss
 | | | theme.scss
 gulpfile.js
 index.html
 package.json
```

I defined gulp as devDependency in package.json:

```
 {
    "devDependencies": {
        "gulp": "^3.5.6"
    }
}
```

Using Gulp, I would like to reach follows:

1. Copy jquery.min.js and bootstrap.min.js into template/js folder to concatenate them into one minified template.min.js (does it totally makes sens or it is better to include js-files directly from bower_components vendor folders?). Please give me a piece of advise.
2. Verify javascripts using gulp-jshint.
3. Compile scss to css with sourcemaps, concatenate them and minify in one theme.css file without extra variables.css using gulp-ruby-sass for windows.

I used [scotch-io/gulp-start](https://github.com/scotch-io/gulp-start/blob/master/gulpfile.js) as an example and reorganize this stuff a bit, but it compiles nothing:

```
var gulp  = require('gulp'),
    gutil = require('gulp-util'),

    jshint     = require('gulp-jshint'),
    sass       = require('gulp-ruby-sass'),
    concat     = require('gulp-concat'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

input  = {
  'sass': 'template/scss/**/*.scss',
  'javascript': 'temaplate/js/**/*.js'
},

output = {
  'stylesheets': 'template/css',
  'javascript': 'template/js'
};

/* run the watch task when gulp is called without arguments */
gulp.task('default', ['watch']);

/* run javascript through jshint */
gulp.task('jshint', function() {
  return gulp.src(input.javascript)
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'));
});

/* compile scss files */
gulp.task('build-css', function() {
  return gulp.src('template/scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(output.stylesheets));
});

/* concat javascript files, minify if --type production */
gulp.task('build-js', function() {
gulp.src('bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
         'bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('template/js/'));  
gulp.src(input.javascript)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(concat('bundle.js'))
    //only uglify if gulp is ran with '--type production'
    .pipe(gutil.env.type === 'production' ? uglify() : gutil.noop()) 
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(output.javascript));
});

/* Watch these files for changes and run the task on update */
gulp.task('watch', function() {
gulp.watch(input.javascript, ['jshint', 'build-js']);
gulp.watch(input.sass, ['build-css']);
});
```

Please, help me to organize this virgin project in the best way. Thanks a lot.